# Storing characters in array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am supposed to create an array with the fixed size (let’s say 5x5). I am supposed to fill it with words typed as command line parameters. I can use only pointers. Obviously I have to create two dimensional array[5][5]. I can’t use more than 25 letters ( I will make if statements ). I am going replace white space with some symbol ($ or something). The problem is I don’t know how to connect those command line parameters with array using only pointers.

Comment: Please provide the code of your attempted solution.

Comment: I will update within a few hours when I will have my internet back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the argc and argv arguments from the main function.

Here is an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("Word %u is: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You compile it using `gcc main.c -o a.exe`.
And run it using `a.exe hello world`.

Edit:

Further to your comment.

You can create an array of pointers like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *my_array_of_strings[5]; // up to 5 strings

    // populate your array
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        my_array_of_strings[i - 1] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);

        if (NULL == my_array_of_strings[i - 1])
        {
            printf("oh no, memory failure");
            break;
        }

        memcpy(my_array_of_strings[i - 1], argv[i], strlen(argv[i]) + 1);

        printf("word is %s\n", my_array_of_strings[i - 1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how command line arguments work. The only problem is connection between CL arguments and array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven’t practiced malloc/calloc but your answer made things understandable from command line point of view.